# What are the Bear caves for?

Tags: anno-1404

Some islands have bear caves on them, but I'm not sure what I am supposed to do with them.

What are the bear caves and what do they do?

How do I harvest this resource?

Comment: I am pretty sure bear pits are for filling with bears. And then luring unsuspecting people whom you don't like to walk over.

Comment: They are really bear caves, not pits. Sorry for ruining the fun.

Comment: ... my offer stands

Comment: @Aardvark Just make sure the bear doesn't rip your head off when you're putting it into the pit (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJAVe57yH-o)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, they are caves ... with bears in them.

You need a Trapper's lodge to get furs from the bear caves. From the fur you can then create fur coats.

You need nobleman to build the Trapper's lodge, so if you can't do it yet you have to advance a bit further.